# Пропали данные из таблиц PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

БД PostgreSQL, сервер AWS. Сначала я работал с БД без указания имени пользователя в *docker-compose*, тогда появлялась ошибка, но я мог управлять базой данных и манипулировать данными в таблицах.

Ошибка:

```
database |      Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 94: "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5"
database | 2020-09-16 00:40:28.127 UTC [55303] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
database | 2020-09-16 00:40:28.127 UTC [55303] DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "postgres".
```

Потом я определил пользователя и пароль в *docker-compose.yml*, и с этого момента таблицы обновились и оказались пустыми - данные исчезли.

Также после этого в pgAdmin4 появилось две новые базы данных, которые потом удалились[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PostgreSQL version: *PostgreSQL 10.9 (Ubuntu 10.9-1.pgdg18.04+1)*

Python v3.8

docker-compose.yml: version 3.1

Помогите, пожалуйста.

код в файле docker-compose:

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  db:
    container_name: database
    image: sameersbn/postgresql:10-2
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    environment:
      PG_USER: $PG_USER
      PG_PASSWORD: $PG_PASSWORD
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - botnet
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  tgbot:
    container_name: bot
    build:
      context: .
    command: python bot.py
    networks:
      - botnet
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    depends_on:
      - db

networks:
  botnet:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Можно увидеть весь docker-compose для БД? Есть ли доступ физически к серверу AWS? Скорей всего после обновления конфигурации docker-compose, если data баз данных не были перекрыты volume'ами, docker создал новые volume для вашего контейнера, а старые данные остались в старом volume'e

Comment: @ASTyurin, обновил